# How to center a form using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center a form containing two inputs(username and password):

```
<h2 align="center" >Authentication</h2>
<form method="post" action="/signin"  class="form-horizontal" role="form" align="center">
    <div class="form-group" align="center">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="username">username<em>*</em></label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" required="true" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="password">password<em>*</em></label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">            
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="true" class="form-control"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">  
            <input type="submit" name="signin" id="signin" value="sign in" class="btn btn-default"/>
         </div>
     </div>     
</form>
```

but when I run the page, the form isn't in the center of the page. I added in the style.css:

```
.form-horizontal{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Setting the margins to auto of course only works if the element’s width is less than that of the container element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Slim Hmidi** Hi there,  You were close with your class of `.form-horizontal`.

Using this will **center** the form in the middle of the page.

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;  
}
```

You will just now need to adjust the `col-sm-xx` within the form to fill and work correctly at all screen sizes.

Here is a screenshot, the blue div that holds the form is centered horizontally.

[image: center form]

Here is the form with the classes in the form changed to fill and work on all screen sizes.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>How to center a form using Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.spacer {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}      
.block {
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 15px;  
  background-color: darkorange;
}  
.block2 {
  min-height: 160px;
  padding-top: 15px; 
} 
.center {
  position: absolute;
/*  top: 0;
  bottom: 0; */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;  
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container col-lg-12 spacer"></div>
    


    <div class="container col-lg-12 block">
        
        <div class="row col-xs-6 block2 bg-primary center">
            
            <form method="post" action="/signin"  class="form-horizontal" role="form" align="center">
            <div class="form-group" >
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="username">username<em>*</em></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" required="true" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="password">password<em>*</em></label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">            
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="true" class="form-control"/> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">  
                    <input type="submit" name="signin" id="signin" value="sign in" class="btn btn-default"/>
                </div>
            </div>     
        </form>
        </div>
            
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

To center a div on the page, you need to set the width of your container, then apply `margin:0 auto;` to it and it will center left and right on the page.

```
.form-horizontal{
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

If you want to center text, just add text-center to the class of the div your text is in. Bootstrap will do the rest.

**Edit 1**

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <h2 align="center" >Authentication</h2>
    <form method="post" action="/signin"  class="form-horizontal" role="form" align="center">
        <div class="form-group" align="center">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="username">username<em>*</em></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" required="true" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="password">password<em>*</em></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">            
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="true" class="form-control"/> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">  
                <input type="submit" name="signin" id="signin" value="sign in" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a problem with h2 tag now.It's shifted compared to the form

Comment: You need to wrap the form and an h2 in a div, then apply the style to that div.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the whole form in `<div class="container">your form HTML</div>`.

Like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJLrOq. Code centers form container to the middle of a site. Edit a CSS and input text's classes to get the layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `text-align: center;` in css .

Comment: Ok,try .form-group{text-align:center; }Please close the question when you have the good answer.